# Highchart mousetracking

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am using Highchart  organization chart and I want to change the behavior of the mousetracking. In this code, when you hover the nodes, only the first parent and the first child will be shown. What I want is that when you hover a node, all related parents and children will be shown. For example now if you hover the 'CFO' only 'CEO' and 'Marketing team' are be showing. But I want to see all related nodes such as < Shareholders + Board + CEO + Marketing team > . can you help me to make this happen? Thank you so much.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: 600,
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
                    nodeId = point.toNode.id,
                    nodeDesc = nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ', ' + nodeId,
                    parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
                return point.index + '. ' + nodeDesc + ', reports to ' + parentDesc + '.';
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Highsoft',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        data: [
            ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
            ['Board', 'CEO'],
            ['CEO', 'CTO'],
            ['CEO', 'CPO'],
            ['CEO', 'CSO'],
            ['CEO', 'HR'],
            ['CTO', 'Product'],
            ['CTO', 'Web'],
            ['CSO', 'Sales'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CSO', 'Market'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CTO', 'Market']
        ],
        levels: [{
            level: 0,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 1,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 2,
            color: '#980104'
        }, {
            level: 4,
            color: '#359154'
        }],
        nodes: [{
            id: 'Shareholders'
        }, {
            id: 'Board'
        }, {
            id: 'CEO',
            title: 'CEO',
            name: 'Atle Sivertsen',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/30081411/portrett-sorthvitt.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'HR',
            title: 'CFO',
            name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
            color: '#007ad0',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131210/Highsoft_04045_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CTO',
            title: 'CTO',
            name: 'Christer Vasseng',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131120/Highsoft_04074_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CPO',
            title: 'CPO',
            name: 'Torstein Hønsi',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131213/Highsoft_03998_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CSO',
            title: 'CSO',
            name: 'Anita Nesse',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131156/Highsoft_03834_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'Product',
            name: 'Product developers'
        }, {
            id: 'Web',
            name: 'Web devs, sys admin'
        }, {
            id: 'Sales',
            name: 'Sales team'
        }, {
            id: 'Market',
            name: 'Marketing team',
            column: 5
        }],
        colorByPoint: false,
        color: '#007ad0',
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        borderColor: 'white',
        nodeWidth: 65
    }],
    tooltip: {
        outside: false
    },
    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 800,
        sourceHeight: 600
    }

});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}

#container h4 {
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#container p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container h4 {
        font-size: 2.3vw;
        line-height: 3vw;
    }

    #container p {
        font-size: 2.3vw;
        line-height: 3vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Organization charts are a common case of hierarchical network charts,
        where the parent/child relationships between nodes are visualized.
        Highcharts includes a dedicated organization chart type that streamlines
        the process of creating these types of visualizations.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure If I understand correctly you. In the described case, It would mean that all nodes will be shown after hover (Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7603rn85/). Basically, in most cases, all nodes are connected in some way, so I'm confused. Could you please clarify what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I mean when a node is hovered, if that node has children and parents, only one of its children and parents will be displayed.
I want to see all its children and parents when a node is hovered.
In other words,I want when a node is hovered, one side of the nodes will be displayed completely. If one of the nodes on the left is clicked, I want to see all the nodes on the left. I hope you can understand me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available out of the box but you can achieve this by writing an algorithm that will check the relationship between the nodes and update its opacity on `point.mouseOver()` and `point.mouseOut()` events. Here is my proposition of the solution:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver() {
            let parents = [];
            let children = [];
            let hovered = this;
            const getParents = (node) => {
              if (node.linksTo) {
                node.linksTo.forEach(link => {
                  let parent = node.series.nodes[link.fromNode.index];
                  parents.push(parent);
                  getParents(parent);
                });
              }
            }

            const getChildren = (node) => {
              if (node.linksFrom) {
                node.linksFrom.forEach(link => {
                  let child = node.series.nodes[link.toNode.index];
                  children.push(child);
                  getChildren(child);
                });
              }
            }

            getParents(hovered);
            getChildren(hovered);


            const family = parents.concat(hovered, children);

            this.series.nodes.forEach(node=> {
                             node.update({
                opacity: 0.1
              }, false)
            });

            family.forEach(node => {
              node.update({
                opacity: 1
              }, false)
            })

            this.series.chart.redraw();
          },
          mouseOut() {
                      this.series.nodes.forEach(node=> {
                             node.update({
                opacity: 1
              }, false)
            });

            this.series.chart.redraw();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6s1djwn7/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.point.events